# how to record normal/PSTN calls using asterisk

Tags: telephony, asterisk, telecommunication

i want to recording incoming calls and outgoing calls using asterisk. when i make a call from my mobile phone with a custom dialer. my calls will not be a voice calls i.e. Voice over ip , that will be the normal trunk calls.

so does anyone has idea how can i recording incoming and outgoing calls at asterisk level and from where should is tart it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MixMonitor command in dialplan

Or you can use Freepbx/Elastix/Trixbox and enable recordings in web.

Asterisk will record only calls sent via pbx.

Comment: as it records calls only sent via PBX does it mean it can record PSTN lines too i mean from mobile to landline also ?

Comment: If you call your asterisk pbx via mobile, after that pstn via provider or some gate - you can record conversation. Or if you do on mobile 2way calling, one leg to your PBX. You can't record conversation which never reach PBX.